# Rename [find-my-iphone] to [find-my]

Tags: discussion, tags

Apple renamed Find My iPhone to [Find My](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/explore/find-my). We should too, because it's not just for iPhones any more.

Proposal: [find-my-iphone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-my-iphone) becomes [find-my](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/find-my)

Comment: I would go with a synonym, actually

Comment: @nohillside why a synonym? It might get confusing having app names and tags being different.

Comment: @FBISurveillanceVan The objective of tags is to group questions by concept, so I would actually consider it a benefit it both tags (which basically are about the same thing) get combined.

Comment: @nohillside could you give an example of a synonym that you would use?

Comment: @FBISurveillanceVan not sure I understand your question here. My idea was to not actually rename the tag but make one to be the synonym of the other.

Comment: @nohillside can we have the synonym setup please - we just had a tag edit adding find-my to something already having find-my-phone (which explicitly says it is for all find-my) https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/394679/revisions - also should find-my-mac be included